# Orange mobile wifi HUAWEI in France

Tags: internet, connection, wifi-driver

I have Huawei from orange mobile wifi in France, and my laptop connects to the network successfully. But, when I want to connect to the Internet, this doesn't work, provided that I tried it on different machines but get the same issue. That is, connect to the network but not to the Internet.

Any ideas on how I can solve this out?

Comment: Chances are all your packets destined for the Internet are being routed to the Great Firewall.

Comment: Do you have credit on the SIM card? Without credit the mobile network is probably dropping your packets on the floor.

Comment: @Mokubai. I have checked the data available which is mre than 2GB. For the credid, how can I check this? Thanks...

Comment: @ta.speot.is. Can you kindly clarify this? And, what should I do in this case? If the firewall on my machine, this is stopped. Thanks...

Comment: Fair enough, I would assume if you have data available then that is equivalent to credit.  How did you determine available data, something on the mobile device?  You might want to edit in a bit more detail to your question and show what steps you have taken, how you can tell that the dongle works and so on. Screenshots may help where necessary.

Comment: @Mokubai. For the available data, when you enter the mobile wifi page, there is a tab called 'statistics' where you can know about the data available. Thanks